# Problems validating Key for Google maps API

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm having problems using google maps api in Android Studio, especially after i create the key for debug mode using cmd and validated it in google console developers so my questions are: 
1) the path for the .android directory when creating the key using keytool is the one in our Users/Our_Name path Correct??
2) using the key that is generated my app using this code:

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.API_KEY"
        android:value="Generated key value"/>
```

this is giving my errors in both values in my manifest.xml
Since the objective is to call a Fragment to show the map isn't this correct???
Am i doing something wrong???

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this google maps API page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup), the proper key name is

`<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>`.

It does also say that `"com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"` may be used for backward compatability. I would try that first, as well as re-checking your setup.